# Do you need to use limit(1) when using first() to load an entity in objectify?

Tags: objectify

If you use the `first()` method such as:

```
Car car = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("vin", "123456789").first().now();
```

Do you need to use `limit(1)` like this `Car car = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("vin", "123456789").limit(1).first().now();` to make sure only one entity is loaded (instead of loading all entities that match the query)? Or will the `first()` method ensure only one entity will be queried for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first()` automatically applies a `limit(1)`.

Don't be shy about navigating to the implementations in your IDE. In IntelliJ, Navigate -> Method Hierarchy is very helpful.